# Check for gems with local :path before deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

For some Rails applications, I'd like to have a safe-guard when I deploy to check if I have some gems configured to be looked up at a local path.

A little bit of context may help to understand.

When I'm in development mode, I want to have a gem in "local mode". In my *Gemfile* it is configured like this : `gem 'my_gem', '~> 0.9', :path => './path/to/my_gem'`.

In production, I want to be like this : `gem 'my_gem', '~> 0.9', :git => 'git@git.example.com:my_gem.git'`.

I've tried to make a shell script (or function) to read the *Gemfile.lock* and exit with an error if the gem is in "local mode".

My deployment scripts could use this to abort if I've forgotten to switch back to the proper mode.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
group :development do
  gem 'my_gem_for_development', '~> 0.9', :require => './path/to/my_gem/lib/my_gem.rb' , :path => './path/to/my_gem/lib'
end
group :production do
  gem 'my_gem', '~> 0.9', :git => 'git@git.example.com:my_gem.git'
end
```

Comment: It's as if you read my mind, picked out all the jumbled pieces and formed it into a cohesive answer built by the gods themselves.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a good idea. But it doesn't help me to check if I've correctly commited my changes in the gem before I commit/deploy the Rails app. That's why I wanted to have a pre-commit or pre-deploy check in the app. I already smell a situation when I'll have everything working great in developpement mode, but in production the gem will not have the right version.

Comment: May be you really should write some gem or rake task and put it in you capistrano recipe

Comment: BTW stackoverflow, sending the comment on a Return keystroke is A BAD IDEA ! KTHXBYE

Comment: I don't now if I'm missing something, but @bor1s answer doesn't work, Bundler is raising ean error : `You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources.`

Comment: jlecour I found the solution to avoid this exeption, I try to use it on mysql2 gem and it works, it should help you too. See my post, I'he edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a gem that you're developing? Why not just write the gem to look at the rails env and change settings based on that. Then you can one canonical version of the gem and you won't have to worry about checking to see which gem version you're using. Otherwise, bor1s' solution will work just fine.

Comment: By the way, you have a great idea!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand your idea regarding the rails env and changing the settings.