# OAuth2 Error during facebook authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth-2.0, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

In development mode, during the authentication callback phase from localhost/auth/facebook, I am faced with the following error

> OAuth2::Error
>   : {"access_token":"XXX","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":123}

This is the location of the error

[image]

This is the stack trace

```
oauth2 (0.9.4) lib/oauth2/client.rb:140:in `get_token'
oauth2 (0.9.4) lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb:29:in `get_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:93:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-facebook (1.6.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:145:in `block in build_access_token'
omniauth-facebook (1.6.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:171:in `with_authorization_code!'
omniauth-facebook (1.6.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:145:in `build_access_token'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:75:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-facebook (1.6.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:71:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
```

I am using the following gem versions

- oauth (0.5.1)
- oauth2 (0.9.4)
- omniauth (1.4.2)
- omniauth-facebook (1.6.0)

I suspect it is an issue with the gems not being compatible with data being sent back by Facebook.

Any pointers on how to go about this challenge?

**Update: Adding image of the error for Deepak**

[image]

Comment: What is the error? Please add the error as well

Comment: Hello deepak, my apologies, I am not fully understand your question properly, as I believe I have shared the error in the first few lines. Regardless, I have added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: The access token return format has changed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994019/facebook-graph-api-not-work-from-2-2-to-2-3 Pretty sure I saw a question about that and owin here in the last couple of days, too, and that the person there fixed it by updating their packages.

Answer (score 5):

You might be using older gem version. It might be a good idea to update the versions if that is feasible for your application.
Also, check that in your environment you are able to talk to Facebook and there are no proxy issues.

Comment: yes, the update is the answer. But it didnt work because I was also using omniauth-soundcloud which depends on an earlier version of oauth2 (omniauth-soundcloud last commit was 5 years ago). so there is a dependency conflict there. I had to fork omniauth-soundcloud and update the gems as suggested in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132479/2-gems-need-different-versions-of-the-same-dependency, then only I can bundle update with no issues.